# Too many soql queries when trying to create a json packet for customers with Active orders

Tags: apex, soql, deployment, governorlimits, production

I'm trying to port over my code below to production but continue to get `System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101`.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/my_endpoint')
global with sharing class clients_w_active_order {
    
    @HttpGet
    global static void doGet (){
        
        List<Order> order_query;
        List<String> acc_name;
        String pre_acc_name;
        String customer_json;
            
        order_query = [Select 
                       Account.Name, 
                       Account.Id, 
                       Account.SF_Acc_ID__c, 
                       Account.Co_ID__c
                        
                        From Order 
                        Where Status = 'Activated' WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
                        ORDER BY Account.Name ASC];
        
        System.debug('order_query: ' + order_query);
        
        
        ActiveOrder ao = new ActiveOrder();
        
        ao.customer_list = new List<customer_list>();
        
        for(Order ord :order_query)
        {
            
            customer_list cl = new customer_list();
            
            if(ord.Account.Name != pre_acc_name && ord.Account.Co_ID__c != null)
            {
                
                if(ord.Account.Name.contains('\'')) 
                {
                    
                    cl.acc_name  = ord.Account.Name.substringBefore('\\');
                }
                
                else
                {
                 
                    cl.acc_name = ord.Account.Name;   
                }
                
                cl.sf_acc_id = ord.Account.SF_Account_ID__c;
                cl.co_acc_id = ord.Account.Co_ID__c;
                pre_acc_name = ord.Account.Name;
                ao.customer_list.add(cl);
            }
        }
        
        System.debug(ao);
        
        customer_json = JSON.serialize(ao);
        System.debug('customer_json: ' + customer_json);
        
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.responseBody = blob.valueOf(customer_json);
    }
    
    public class ActiveOrder
    {
        
        public List<customer_list> customer_list;
    }
    
    public class customer_list
    {
        
        public string acc_name;
        public string sf_acc_id;
        public string co_acc_id;
    }
}
```

How can I prevent reaching the governor limits? how can I improve on what I already have so that when the customer count goes past 99 it won't reach the governor limit when a get is performed on this endpoint?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Looking at the code provided, I cannot see any reason for hitting limits. Are you sure this is the correct and complete code for where the issue occurs? Please [edit] your question to add detail of the line on which you get the exception and to explain the context where it happens. My only guess is some unit test that calls this code in a loop and that has all data visible instead of creating its own test data...